# How Event Bubbling works and what is it?

Tags: javascript, events

NB: **This question was marked as dup with [Difference between Event Bubbling and Event Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), but it isn't.I am trying to ask basic of what is Event,Target and TagName. I want to understand, what is even, what is target and tagName, as it is like arguments passed in a function.**

I am trying to understand `events` and `target`, in other words Event Bubbling, I am totally confused over what is it and how to understand it,I know everything is a event but can someone would be able to explain in some analogy, where is easy to understand with a example

```
document.addEventListener = ("click", (event) => {
   event.target.tagName
});
```

tagName is something i want to know to.

Comment: @caisah no i read that but it doesn't satisfy my question

Comment: Bubbling is a small part of events. The event object doesn't have a great deal to do with bubbling. Target should be [easy enough to learn about](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=event+target&t=he&ia=web) without resorting to stackoverflow. `tagName` has nothing to do with events and is [also easy to research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+tagName&t=ha&ia=web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have misnamed your question. From your edit, it sounds like you really want to know more about the `event` object and in particular, the `target` and `target.tagName` properties.

Here is an example of event bubbling in action, showing off the properties in question:

- `event` holds metadata about the event that occurred;
- `event.target` holds a reference to the original event source, for example the button clicked;
- `event.target.tagName` is just the name of the `target`'s tag in uppercase, e.g. `'DIV'` or `'P'`;
- `event.currentTarget` holds a reference to the node to which the event listener was attached.

```js
let handler = event => {
  console.log('Handler fired!')
  console.log('Event listener attached to:', event.currentTarget)
  console.log('Event originally occurred on:', event.target)
}

document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click', handler)
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener('click', handler)
document.body.addEventListener('click', handler)
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <button id="inner">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i wanted, you may want to edit question as i am not a native english speaker. However i am a bit confused over `event` and `target`. Can i say `target` is like `click` or `keydown` or `keypress`, but then again wouldn't it be a `event`, like event says. Everything you do e.g scroll, click, `keydown`, `keypress`, `zoom` or `pan` is a `event`, or i am missing something>

Comment: `event.target` is a DOM node on your page, like a `<div>` or `<a>`. The attribute that holds e.g. `keydown` or `click` would be `event.type`.

Comment: I did something like this `document.addEventListener("click" , function(event){
  console.log("The" + event + "is clicked and" + event.target + "is targeted using tagname of " + event.target.tagName);
})` while i am getting grip of it, What i don't understand is when the above is output, it is broken down like it should `[HTMLLIElement]` but when i do `event.target.tagName` it gives me full elements and its content, why the difference

Comment: The `target` itself is an object with properties like `textContent` and `tagName` (which are both strings). When you print an object to the console, it either turns it into a string like `'[HTMLLIElement]'` or shows you all of its properties as a tree. Strings, on the other hand, will always be printed as a string.

Comment: Great, I will have a go with your last comment, will try to digest it, but thanks for the great example and explanation!